# How to create a bootbox prompt with a bootstrap datepicker as input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootbox

I am creating a dialog box using bootbox.

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message: 'Datepicker input: <input id="date"></input>',
    title: "Custom label",
    buttons: {
        main: {
            label: "Save",
            className: "btn-primary",
            callback: function () {
                console.log("Hi " + $('#first_name').val());
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#date").datepicker(); //Not working
```

Any idea about how to create a bootbox prompt with datepicker input? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This workaround did it for me. Any better approch to this issue is welcome.

```
function BootboxContent() {
    var frm_str = '<form id="some-form">'
        + '<div class="form-group">'
        + '<label for="date">Date</label>'
        + '<input id="date" class="date span2 form-control input-sm" size="16" placeholder="dd-mm-yy" type="text">'
        + '</div>'
        + '</form>';

    var object = $('<div/>').html(frm_str).contents();

    object.find('.date').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $(this).blur();
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });

    return object
}

//Show the datepicker in the bootbox
bootbox.dialog({
    message: BootboxContent,
    title: "Reschedule Rule",
    buttons: {
        main: {
            label: "OK",
            className: "btn-primary"
        }
    }
});
```

The datepicker will show behind the modal overlay. In the datepicker.css, add **z-index: 99999 !important** to the **.datepicker**

To ajust the calender right under the datepicker input depending on the position of your bootbox dialog box, add the follow style:

```
.modal-open .datepicker {
    left: 52% !important; //Change it according to the position of your dialog
    top: 25% !important; //Change it according to the position of your dialog
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question for an Ember project I was working on. Applying my solution to your code would look like this:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message: 'Datepicker input: <input id="date"></input>',
    title: 'Custom label',
    buttons: {
        main: {
            label: 'Save',
            className: 'btn-primary',
            callback() {
                console.log("Hi " + $('#first_name').val());
            }
        }
    }
}).datepicker();
```

Simply add the `datepicker()` to the end of your Bootbox call. Worked for me on my project, hope it works for you in yours.

Comment: It's wonderful! Thank you very much! However, I think we can use more detail: bootbox.dialog({...}).find("#date").datepicker();